# Intellij refactor type migration does nothing

Tags: java, refactoring

I am trying to change the type of License from string to int.  I right click on"string" and  chose type migration but nothing happens, What is this the correct way to to this ?

```
public class Worker implements Driver {

    private String wid;
    private String password;
    private String name;
    private String terms;
    private String position;
    private String license;
    private String bank;

    private int salary;
    private int startDay;
    private int startMonth;
    private int startYear;
   private int connected;
}
```

Comment: How do you do that? Because I can change type. Also, it is possible, that you use somewhere that fields, so it wouldn't be possible to change

Answer (score 0):

As is stated in the documentation of the [Type Migration](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/type-migration.html). For the type migration to work you have to select the type you want to migrate. **String** next to `license` in your case. It does not work when you select the variable name.

Comment: i do click on "string"" not on license

Comment: Then it should work. It might be stuck. Try to restart it or invalidate its cache (In the top left corner File->Invalidate Caches/restart).

Answer (score 0):

When Migrating Type it seems IntelliJ does not by default select 'All Places' as scope. Mine selected a random scope which did not include the file I was editing.

Answer (score 0):

I thought it was doing nothing after I was skipping the preview, but I believe it was silently aborting because it found conflicts. I had to view preview, then proceed and 'ignore' conflicts. That said, It's currently been running for a few *hours* and I'm afraid to stop it at this point. I'll update when it's done to confirm or add more information.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34165142)